# Jquery: Change existing price with checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkout form where the base price is $249.99. The user has the option to add a desk and or chair for $99.99. As of right now the price changes, but removes the base price instead of adding to it. And upon de-selection, it actually subtracts the base price leaving a total of $0.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    var names = $(':checked').map(function(){
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    var spans = $('span.amount');
    spans[1].innerHTML = sum;
});
```

I've made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XSCZ3/6/) to show what I mean. So how do I get the base price to stay $249.99 and do the proper math? Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues.

Change your sum to initialize at 249.99.

Last line should change 2 lines of code that show the sum.
http://jsfiddle.net/XSCZ3/12/

Why are you only changing the button price. You should change the button price and the final price heading on the top of the fiddle.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var sum = 249.99;
    var names = $(':checked').map(function(){
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    //var spans = $('span.amount'); No need for this
    //spans[1].innerHTML = sum;  No need for this
    $('span.amount').text(sum); //Change to this.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, so simple. I need sleep. But it's returning `NaN` on my local. Thoughts?

Comment: using Django and forgot `{% csrf_token %}` in the form. But I dont think that would cause that

Answer (score 6):

Why `sum = 0` ? Shouldn't it be 249.99 in the given example ?

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/XSCZ3/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize your `sum` variable like: `var sum = 249.99;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/vANz4/